# In Santorini, does a god power replace original win condition

Tags: santorini

Just starting playing this game.  My wife chose chronus, and I chose eros.  Both have alternate win conditions.

Do you have to win via these conditions? Or can you also win by reaching the third pillar as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**You can win by reaching the third pillar with both those gods.**

Per the [rules](http://files.roxley.com/Santorini-Rulebook-Web-2016.08.14.pdf), the win conditions of Chronus and Eros both start with:

> You also win if ...

Also indicates an additional win condition.  Completing either will earn you the win.

This is spelled out on page 2 of the rules as well

> Additional Win Conditions are
> specified by some God Powers. In addition to
> being able to win by moving up onto the third
> level during your turn, you can also win by
> fulfilling the “Win Condition” described.